# Google In app Billing V3 ERROR Code

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

**In app Billing v3** returns Response Code **(BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_USER_CANCELED:1) -1005** in more than one scenario.

Launching the purchase flow opens the Google Play-like UI. Whenever an error happens in this UI, say a network disconnection / Timeout / Item Unavailable /  Item Already Purchased, a dialog pops up to indicate the error. When OK is clicked , **Response code : User Cancelled(1)** is invariably returned in the OnActivityResult Intent extras. According to the reference on Android developer's site this is supposed to happen only when the user cancels the activity/Dialog, which i clearly don't do.

I would like to separate out the different errors and handle them individually in my app. Having a single error code returned doesn't help. Any one faced it yet? Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, this seems to  be an issue with the Google Play client. Google has started rolling out updates to the GP client as versions 4.0+ and the bug appears to be fixed.

Comment: I am still getting this error a lot from devices running Android versions all the way form 2.3.x to 4.2.2. Maybe all my customers are changing their minds at the last moment, but I am not so sure about this.

Answer (score 0):

The TrivialDrive demo tests the onActivityResult() callback for the value Activity.RESULT_CANCELED,
and assumes that if that is the value returned then the user has canceled.

That is an incorrect assumption, because if the responseCode in that activity result is BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED (=7) then Activity.RESULT_CANCELED means that
the in-app billing service would not allow the purchase because the item is already owned.
This response code is working for me.

However, once that possibility is eliminated, I've found that it's safe to assume that the user has canceled.  I haven't checked very recently however to see if Google has made the BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_USER_CANCELED response code directly testable and reliable.